# Load different tables based on slicer value

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have loaded 3 tables in PowerBi desktop can created their visuals for a report.
Now I want a slicer or kind of it so that when a user first see the page then they can select parameter or slicer value for the 3 loaded tables and based on their selection the respective table will show up along with its visuals whatever is created.

I have created new table with 3 values like A,B,C to refer to 3 different tables.But I have no idea how to link it to the 3 different tables pages  and how can I invoke the respective referenced table based on the value

Comment: Can you use a relationship to connect your new table to a column in the other tables?